# Skipped If Statement/unstripped input data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm updating a crack the code game I made in Python so that you can play a single-player game against the computer. For some reason, the interpreter either doesn't use the data stripped from the input used to determine player count or skips the if statement that uses the stripped data from the input. Either way, after you input the player number it goes straight to the guessing code with an empty list of correct code characters.

My code for the player count determining and code creation is:

```
plyrs = 0
correctanswer = []
print('Welcome!')
plyrs = str(input('How many players are there? (minimum 1, maximum 2) '))
if plyrs == 2:
    print("I'm gonna ask you for some alphanumerical (number or letter characters to make a code for the other player to guess.")
    input('Press enter when you are ready to enter in the code!') #Like all of my games, it has a wait.
i = 0
    while i < 4:
        correctanswer.append(input('What would you like digit ' + str(i + 1) + " to be? "))
        i = i + 1
    print("Ok, you've got your code!")
    i = 0
    while i < 19: #Generates seperator to prevent cheating
        print('')
        i = i + 0.1
    print("Now, it's the other player's turn to guess!")
elif plyrs == 1:
    import random
    characters  = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
    i = 0
    while i < 4:
        correctanswer.append(characters[randint(0,36)])
        i = i + 1
    print('Time for you to guess!')
print('')
```

No other skipping if statement questions apply to this so please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plyrs` is a string, and you're comparing it to an int. `"2" == 2` will always be false. Same with `plyrs == 1`, this will be false throughout.

Comment: How would I turn it into a int? I used the int() function on the input so either that isn't a correct answer or I'm doing something wrong

Comment: nvm I used str() for some reason

Comment: You'll need to raise a `ValueError` if you want to safely handle bad inputs (non-numerical inputs)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099379/limit-input-to-integer-only-text-crashes-python-program) is a link to help you with that