# I need help populating a dictionary with user input, with predetermined keys, inside a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, dictionary

I'm creating a function (python 2.7) to make a dictionary out of user input with test subject as the key and their test scores as the values, the subjects that the scores will correspond to are provided in a seperate list called subjects so i will require a for loop to cycle through them asking the user for the scores in turn. The function will return the student ID and the scores.
I think it's something like this:

```
subjects = 'english', 'maths', 'science'

dict = {}

     for a in subjects:

         testscore = raw_input("please enter your test score: ")
         dict[a] = testscore
```

Really struggling, any help appreciated! 
thanks

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: `subjects = [ ... ]`, fix indent, don't call your dict `dict`, fix indentation, and should be OK

Comment: indentation and add that please raw_input("please enter your {0} test score: ".format(a))

Comment: Maybe mention a in the query, so the user knows, for what subject he's putting the score `"please enter the test score for " +str(a)`

Comment: Also don't name your dict `dict` - it shadows the builtin `dict` type (and it's a bad naming scheme anyway, a good name should describe the function of the variable, not it's type).

Comment: What's your question exactly ? So far you described what you have to do and what you've done, but not your actual problem.

Comment: the problem was that it wasn't functioning but with the indentation issue and naming things correctly it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
subjects = ['english', 'maths', 'science']

scores = {}

for a in subjects:
    testscore = raw_input("please enter the score for "+str(a)+": ")
    scores[a] = testscore
```

`subjects` must be a list (or any other iterable).
Other fixes as in the comments.

Comment: what's wrong with string formatting ? `raw_input("please enter the score for {} :".format(a))`. And anyway since here `a` is already a string, you don't need to call `str()` on it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with string formatting. I just wanted to demonstrate the possibility of adding strings together in general.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. Also, one final thing, how would I ensure that the user input for the score is a float and is between 0 and 100 for neatness sake.

Comment: @SamuelEwen why don't you try something by yourself first ? How do you hope to learn anything if you don't do your homework ? Asking for help is ok, but only as long as you _really_ tried by yourself first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099379/limit-input-to-integer-only-text-crashes-python-program