# This program calculates the BMI of a person. How can I prevent user from inputting a zero without having to use another conditional loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
flag='yes'
#while loop for reccursion
while flag != 'no':
    print ("\n BMI Calculator")
    #Exception block for catching non integer inputs
    try:
        #Prompting user to input weight
        weight = int(input('Enter your weight in pounds : '))
        while weight == 0:
            sys.exit()
    except ValueError:
        print ('Oops!! Kindly enter only numbers.')
        flag = input('Do you want to try again? yes/no : ')
        continue

    try:
        #Prompting user to input height
        height = float(input('Enter your height in inches : '))
        while height == 0:
            sys.exit()
    except ValueError:
        print ('Oops!! Kindly enter only numbers.')
        flag = input('Do you want to try again? yes/no : ')
        continue

    #Function for calculating BMI    
    def bmi_calculator():
        #Exception block for catching division by zero
        try:
            #Formula for calculating BMI
            BMI = round(weight * 703/(height*height), 2)
            return (BMI)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print ('Oops!! Cannot divide by zero.')
            sys.exit()
```

Is there any exception handling available for accepting only non zero inputs? Is there any way to avoid another while or if loop?

Comment: This isn't exactly what you want, but you can throw an exception if a value is zero.  This will require an if statement though.  An example is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099379/limit-input-to-integer-only-text-crashes-python-program)

Comment: Why don't you want to use an if loop? Also, why auto exit for == 0?

Comment: I was thinking using while and if would increase the number of lines and code but  "if weight == 0:
                     raise ValueError"                                                                                   This serve my purpose without adding extra lines so its fine.

Comment: Maybe you want to prevent negative numbers too.

Comment: @Marichyasana. yup, I used "if weight <= 0" to prevent negative numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle 0 numbers properly one of the ways is to raise exception when 0 is entered:

```
#Function for calculating BMI    
def bmi_calculator():
    flag='yes'
    while flag != 'no':
        print ("\n BMI Calculator")
        #Exception block for catching non integer inputs
        try:
            #Prompting user to input weight
            weight = int(input('Enter your weight in pounds : '))
            if weight == 0:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print ('Oops!! Kindly enter non-zero numbers only.')
            flag = input('Do you want to try again? yes/no : ')
            continue

        try:
            #Prompting user to input height
            height = float(input('Enter your height in inches : '))
            if height == 0:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print ('Oops!! Kindly enter non-zero numbers only.')
            flag = input('Do you want to try again? yes/no : ')
            continue

        #Formula for calculating BMI
        BMI = round(weight * 703/(height*height), 2)
        return (BMI)

print(bmi_calculator())
```

Also I replaced your `while weight == 0` and `while height == 0` by if statements - they look more appropriate and I placed the main while loop inside of the function defintion `bmi_calculator` so that it can be called whenever you need it.

Comment: **Thank you!!**. Exactly what I was looking for.